# Bash script to find like lines in column 1 between two files and output to two new files

Tags: bash

I have two files that have a list of metropolitan cities in column one and varying data in the remaining columns.  What I am trying to do is create two new files so that column 1 in both files are identical.  Meaning I want to remove any rows in both files that don't exist in the other file.  Both file are CSV.

Example File 1

```
"Austin, TX",123,1234,12345
"Beaumont, TX",123,1234,12345
"Charlotte, NC",123,1234,12345
"Detroit, MI",123,1234,12345
```

Example File 2

```
"Austin, TX",abc,dbas,woeij
"Baytown, TX",abc,dbas,woeij
"Charlotte, NC",abc,dbas,woeij
"Denver, CO",abc,dbas,woeij
```

Output File 1

```
"Austin, TX",123,1234,12345
"Charlotte, NC",123,1234,12345
```

Output File 2

```
"Austin, TX",abc,dbas,woeij
"Charlotte, NC",abc,dbas,woeij
```

Comment: You forgot to add your code :-)

Comment: Also where you are currently stuck.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -f <(grep -oP '^".*?"' file2.txt) file1.txt
```

Output:

```
"Austin, TX",123,1234,12345
"Charlotte, NC",123,1234,12345
```

---

```
grep -f <(grep -oP '^".*?"' file1.txt) file2.txt
```

Output:

```
"Austin, TX",abc,dbas,woeij
"Charlotte, NC",abc,dbas,woeij
```